# What's the purpose of kslowd?

Tags: ubuntu, unix, daemon

I'm running Ubuntu 10.10:

```
uname -a
Linux mt-xps 2.6.35-22-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP Sat Oct 16 20:45:36 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When I run top, I occasionally see a "kslowd000" or similar process popping up in the top CPU usage list. I've tried googling kslowd, but found no explanation to what it is. manpages also don't help.

What does it do ? And how would I find out myself ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a kernel thread performing things that typically take a lot of time. For more information, see [slow-work.txt](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/slow-work.txt).

Comment: Thanks. Is there some sort of manpage or other lookup mechanism for this, or do you have to know/guess/google which daemon name is connected to which feature, and part of the Kernel or another program ?

Comment: Guess, Google or just plain know. :-) OK, there are books and so on written about kernel, but they are usually _very_ hard to read and understand. Kernel internals is not the easiest thing on Earth ...

Comment: That's kinda disappointing, really. There's usually a lot of info for first-time users via the graphical help, and there's mind-numbing technical detail via man pages etc. But to find out concepts and which thing (program/daemon/folder/abbreviation) belongs to which other, you have to guess or ask dumb-sounding questions.

Comment: Yeah. There are various sites such as http://kernelnewbies.org/ easing your journey into kernel internals, but for bigger picture the documentation lacks in many cases.

Comment: One hint - "processes" that are listed in ps output with square brackets:  [kslowd000]  are usually (always?) kernel threads.

Answer (score 0):

To debug kslowd, you'll need to enable debugging in the kernel (and recompile is necessary) by adding to your kernel config:

> CONFIG_SLOW_WORK_DEBUG=y

Reboot, then run

> watch -n0 cat /sys/kernel/debug/slow_work/runqueue